# Automatically close the window browser when the image is saved in AJAX JSON C# ASPNET

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, ajax, gridview

In my `GridView` in `C# ASP.NET 4` I insert a button to edit the row of `GridView` that open a new webpage on the browser in this mode

```
protected void btn1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ImageButton btn1 = (ImageButton)sender;
    GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)btn.NamingContainer;
    int oID = Convert.ToInt32(gv.DataKeys[row.RowIndex].Values[0]);

    string queryString = "newpage.aspx?oID=" + oID.ToString();
    string newWin = "window.open('" + queryString + "','_blank');";
    ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "pop", newWin, true);
}
```

The `newpage.aspx` use `Ajax` and `JSON` for save an image on the server in this mode

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#btnSave").click(function () {
            var image = document.getElementById("cc").toDataURL("image/png");
            image = image.replace('data:image/png;base64,', '');
            var qString = "?" + window.location.href.split("?")[1];
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'newpage.aspx/oImage' + qString,
                data: '{ "imageData" : "' + image + '" }',
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                dataType: 'json',

                success: function (msg) {
                    alert('Ok');
                },

                failure: function (msg) {
                    alert(response.d);
                },

                error: function (msg) {
                    alert(response.d);
                },

                error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                    alert("error : " + thrownError + JSON.stringify(image));
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

The process works correctly but I need to automatically close the window in which the page `newpage.aspx` is open after the image is saved

I have tried inserting another button for manually close of `newpage.aspx`, but the window doesn't close

Tested in browsers IE 11, Edge and Chrome the result doesn't change the window doesn't close

```
protected void btnclose_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{
    this.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "Close", "window.close()", true);
}
```

Any suggestion?

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of server-side button add client-side button, that will do the job

```
 <button type="button" onclick="closeme()">Close me</button>
    <script>
        function closeme() {
            this.window.close();
        }
    </script>
```

this will helps